# IE10 extjs compatibility app view issue

Tags: internet-explorer, extjs, internet-explorer-10, extjs2

i have some application write in extjs2.3, and when i test it with IE10 i can see several issue, node don't expand, form don't rendering well etc...With IE9 or in other Browser Mode  compatibile view all is rendering well..

I use all the solution i find with google use 
`<!DOCKTYPE html>` or 
`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">`

I start to porting all my app to new version of extjs but for now i need to find a solution to change it for have a compatibility view.

Any type of help is usefull.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

RE-EDIT: For know i put this in the first line after the declare `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8" >` and is going all well. If anyone have another solution just say..